# Question about proof that $A\subset B \implies \overline{A}\subset \overline{B}$

Tags: general-topology

Look at this simple proof that $A\subset B \implies \overline{A}\subset \overline{B}$:

$\overline{B}$ is a set that contains $B$, therefore it contains $A$. Since it's closed and contains $A$, it must contain $\overline{A}$.

This made sense for me intuitively, but how do I prove the last sentence?

> Since $\overline{B}$ it's closed and contains $A$, it must contain $\overline{A}$.

Comment: What is your definition of closure? Some definitions makes that statement completely trivial to prove ("$\overline A$ is the intersection of all closed sets that contains $A$" or similar), while with other definitions it requires some proof ("$\overline A$ is the set that contains all points of $A$ together with all limit points of $A$", or anything concerning sequences, for instance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, $\bar A$ is the intersection of the closed subsets which contain $A$ so $\bar A$ is contained in evey closed subset which contains $A$, since $A\subset \bar B$ and $\bar B$ is closed, $\bar A\subset\bar B$.

Comment: Thanks, that was the definition they gave me

Answer (score 0):

$\bar C$ is the intersection of the set of all closed sets that have $C$ as a subset. Let $A^*$ be the set of all closed sets that have $A$ as a subset. Let $B^*$ be the set of all closed sets that have $B$ as a subset. If $A\subset B$ then $A^*\supset B^*,$ which implies $\bar A=\cap A^*\subset \cap B^*=\bar B.$